# PHP Contact Form - How to check server side validation

Tags: php, validation, contact-form

I'm learning about contact forms in PHP and am trying to check my server side validation that I moved into another php file.

Using the validation in the same file as the form works fine, but I'd like to separate the PHP validation logic into it's own file and call it from the form.

e.g.,

```
<form action="validate.php">
```

When moving the server side validation logic into it's own file, and I submit an empty form, I get the redirect to validate2.php with no errors and a blank page.

Is there something I'm missing to get this to work? I've tried turning off HTML5 validation using `novalidate` in the form to check for the server validations.

How can I fix this?

**Form**

```
<h1>Contact Form</h1>
    <?php echo $result; ?>

    <form action="validate.php" method="POST" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" required></textarea>
         </div>

         <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Submit">
     </form>
```

**Validation**

```
<?php

$error = null;

if ($_POST["submit"]) {
$result = 'Form submitted';
if (!$_POST['name']) {
    $error = "<br />Please enter your name";
}

if (!$_POST['email']) {
    $error .= "<br />Please enter your email address";
}

if (!$_POST['comment']) {
    $error .= "<br />Please enter a comment";
}

if ($_POST['email']!="" AND !filter_var($_POST['email'],
        FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error .= "<br />Please enter a valid email address";
}

if ($error) {
    $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There were error(s) in your form:</strong>'.$error.'</div>';
} else {
    if (mail("example@gmail.com", "Comment from website!", "Name: ". $_POST['name']." Email: ".$_POST['email']." Comment: ".$_POST['comment'])) {
        $result = '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Thank you!</strong> I\'ll be in touch.</div>';
    } else {
        $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry, there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
    }
}
header('Location: contact_form.php');
}
```

Comment: have you checked whether you are getting $_POST values on the page?

Comment: I've added a var_dump($_POST) on the validate.php page to check and i am getting back POST values. `array(4) { ["name"]=> string(4) "aaaa" ["email"]=> string(9) "aa@aa.com" ["comment"]=> string(5) "aaaaa" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" }`

Comment: Have you tried step by step duugging? Check whether you are going inside the  if ($_POST["submit"]) { condition then print error (print_r($error)) below if ($error) {

Comment: Yes, adding a `print_r($error)` shows me the error messages when submitting the blank form. `Please enter your name
Please enter your email address
Please enter a comment` without `print_r` it's a blank page, do I need to do a redirect back to the contact_form?

Comment: Yes you have to redirect back to contact form. Otherwise it will stay on validation.php itself,

Comment: Added a `header('Location: contact_form.php');` to the validation.php file, it redirects but no error messages are appearing.

Comment: I posted an answer. try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before redirecting assign message in session like below

```
<?php
    session_start();


    $error = null;

    if ($_POST["submit"]) {
    $result = 'Form submitted';
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $error = "<br />Please enter your name";
    }

    if (!$_POST['email']) {
        $error .= "<br />Please enter your email address";
    }

    if (!$_POST['comment']) {
        $error .= "<br />Please enter a comment";
    }

    if ($_POST['email']!="" AND !filter_var($_POST['email'],
            FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error .= "<br />Please enter a valid email address";
    }

    if ($error) {
        $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There were error(s) in your form:</strong>'.$error.'</div>';
    } else {
        if (mail("example@gmail.com", "Comment from website!", "Name: ". $_POST['name']." Email: ".$_POST['email']." Comment: ".$_POST['comment'])) {
            $result = '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Thank you!</strong> I\'ll be in touch.</div>';
        } else {
            $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry, there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
        }
    }

    if(isset($result) && !empty($result)) {
          $_SESSION['error'] = $result;
    }

   header('Location:contact_form.php');
   exit;
   } 
    ?>
```

In contact_form.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['error']) && !empty($_SESSION['error'])) {
        print_r($_SESSION['error'])
    }
?>
```

At the bottom of the contact_form page

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['error']) && !empty($_SESSION['error'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['error']);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Ok tried this, and added the code in the contact_form.php (one at the top of the page) and the other at the bottom after the `</html>` closing tag. And nothing no errors are appearing when submitting an empty form. I get a `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION` on the `unset($_SESSION['error])` line.

Comment: Have you placed exit after header('Location: contact_form.php'); ? have you started session at the validate.php ? session_start();

Comment: Check my updated code you have to start session on both validate.php and contactform.php

Comment: Yes, and still no error messages are appearing. (the notice went away but no error messages)

Comment: have you started session on both validate.php and cotactform.php?

Comment: Yes sir. Same results, except I get a session has already been started message if I have it in both places.

Comment: I have modified validate.php codings, update and check, have you started session any other file and include the file in validate.php or contact form.php

Comment: Ok, now the errors are appearing. I don't need a session_start(); in the contact form for it to work. Now can you explain to me, why it wasn't working before? And now it does with sessions?

Comment: When you redirect the page, it will carry message through get, post or session variable otherwise it will loose.

Comment: Thank you sir, for the help and explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

```
    if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
     {
    if (isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name']=="") {
         $error = "<br />Please enter your name";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['email'])&& $_POST['email']=="") {
         $error .= "<br />Please enter your email address";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['comment'])&& $_POST['comment']=="") {
         $error .= "<br />Please enter a comment";
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['email']) AND !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error .= "<br />Please enter a valid email address";
    }
if ($error) {
    $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There were error(s) in your form:</strong>'.$error.'</div>';
?>
<script>
window.location.href='';
</script>
<?php }else{}?>
```

use like this

Comment: Using this, and submitting an empty form still redirects me to `validate.php` and a blank page with no errors.

Comment: just updated the code if error occurs than it will redirect you to wherever you want give url in window.location.href='';

Comment: Added a `header('Location: contact_form.php');` to the validation.php file, it redirects but no error messages are appearing.

Comment: header('Location: contact_form.php?error=$error'); use this and get error variable on contact_form page like $_GET['error']and show there like echo $_GET['error'];

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it's not giving any errors doing this.

Comment: ok than first check error on the current page before redirecting if not showing or not

Comment: `isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name']==""` can be shortened to `empty($_POST['name'])`